# Clingo beginner looking for some guidance

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am very new to Clingo and I am having trouble developing an OR condition to work.
My idea is to create a rule that find a mention of the word "burner" in the content OR the App (basically combining the "contains_burner_content" and "contains_burner_app"). I have tried using 'not' but it doesnt seem to work.

I am also trying to see if its possible to use some sort of wildcard in the content to find any mention of the word "burner" rather than exact, however everything I have seen suggests this isnt possible.

Below is my code that I have developed so far.

```
activity("Not", "unknown", "910-248-4781", "2022-12-01", "12:16", "Login", "burner").
activity("Burner", "unknown", "910-248-4781", "2022-12-01", "12:19", "Created My Burner number", "unknown").
activity("Burner", "unknown", "910-248-4781", "2022-12-01", "13:28", "Received Picture", "OG use of Cookies").
activity("Burner", "unknown", "910-248-4781", "2022-12-01", "13:30", "Saved Picture", "OG use of Cookies").
activity("Burner", "unknown", "910-248-4781", "2022-12-01", "13:31", "Sent Message", "burner").

% Rule to identify activities where 'Content' contains the word "burner"
contains_burner_content(App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content) :-
    activity(App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content),
    contains_word_burner(Content).
    
contains_burner_app(App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content) :-
    activity(App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content),
    contains_word_burner(App).
    
contains_word_burner(Content) :- Content = "burner".
contains_word_burner(App) :- App = "Burner".

#show contains_burner_content/7.
#show contains_burner_app/7.
```

I am hoping to combine my two rules into one, also any help in the wildcard would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Good start.

First, I want to start pointing out that the 2 rules

```
contains_word_burner(Content) :- Content = "burner".
contains_word_burner(App) :- App = "Burner".
```

are actually the same and you can even shorten it to the following (assuming capital letters do not matter)

```
contains_word_burner("burner").
```

About the or: You can implement it using cardinality constraints:

```
contains_burner_content(App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content) :-
    activity(App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content), 
    1{contains_word_burner(Content) ; contains_word_burner(App)}.
```

this reads: for every `activity` where at least one of `contains_word_burner(Content)` and  `contains_word_burner(App)` holds, `contains_burner_content` holds as well for the same arguments.

To read more about the syntax you can consult the [slides](https://github.com/potassco-asp-course/course/releases/download/v1.21.0/main.pdf) from potassco.

Comment: Could I also use disjunction rules to do this as well? 

After researching it seems that there are like an OR statement, so by having the same Head but with different Body, multiple conditions could be set so that even if one of these conditions are met, the rule is true and is then shown?

contains_burner(MessageID, App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content) :-
    activity(MessageID, App, ContactID, PhoneNumber, Date, Time, Action, Content),
    contains_word_burner(App).

contains_word_burner(App) :- App = "burner".
contains_word_burner(App) :- App = "Burner".